# Terminal and Software Center Dissapear, Unity will not initialize after Power Cycle

Tags: unity, 13.04, virtualbox

I am currently running on a live USB.

I was trying to boot up a windows XP iso on VirtualBox when Terminal and Software Center completely disspeared from my system (Ctrl-Alt-T does not work). My first instinct was that something got misconfigured in the VB install, so I power cycled.

Now, Unity does not start (Other programs are still running, as I am getting desktop notifications from Chrome and such). I've tried dpkg and all the recovery options from GRUB.

Is there perhaps any way to re-install Ubuntu while keeping the files intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-install and keep files intact, keep in mind that there is no **guarantee** all your files will be intact.  So its best to have a **backup** handy just in-case.  Plus the best way that I recommend that you do a fresh install once you get all your files.

To get your files, just copy the folders that you want to save like Downloads, Documents, Music, etc. to a different partition, Re-install Ubuntu, and after the installation is done copy the folders over.

For reference, the best way you can preserve your settings is to use a separate /home partition. That way, whenever you re-install, just define your /home partition by selecting Something Else, to create manual partitions and choose not to format it. Make sure you have 3 partition. `/`, `/home` and `Swap`.

To get a list of applications that you have installed so you can install them once you re-install Ubuntu, you can use the Ubuntu Software Center to see installed applications.

Comment: Yeah, I found out I can re-install from the live disk, and that f'd up things more. I installed a new copy into a partion and moved over all my files just fine.